# Difference between $request->files->get and $form-<get method in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, foreach

On my symfony project I have an ajax call to upload multiple files.Currently accessing it by

```
$files = $request->files->get('file');
```

But for further coding used foreach on $files variable but not working.

On another page have the same functionality but that is page submit so accessing with $form object that is working fine there.

```
$form->get('file')->getData();
```

What is the difference between this parameter accessing method please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: Because the `file` field doesn't exist in the second case.

The more detailed explanation is this:

The [Form Component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form.html#configuration) is built on top of [HttpFoundation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html) (that provides an object-oriented way to deal with requests and responses) and some other symfony components and provides not only the form builder but validation, csrf protection, object mapping and other goodies.

In the first example you are using the [`File ParameterBag`](https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/6.1/FileBag.php) provided by `HttpFoundation`. It's basically the `$_FILES` superglobal, and you are accessing the one named `file` in particular. As it's an ajax call, I'd bet is a handcrafted form or a purely js function; the `file` field is named just that. In this case you are dealing directly with the raw http request. Bob's your uncle.

When using the form component however, if you have a form field named `file` it won't show up in the request as such; the form is sent as an array in the form:

```
[
  'form_name' => [
    'field1' => 'value1',
    // More fields or nested arrays
  ],
];
```

The component does this to allow for multiple forms with the same fields while being able to identify them, etc.

As part of the form handling, the fields in the request are mapped back to the form fields. That's what your app is using in the second case, the `Form` object representation of the data sent. For more information about the process, refer to [the documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form.html#handling-form-submissions). You can also inspect the request with your browser tools or the Symfony Profiler to gain more insight.